# What's the proper way to switch between dark and light modes on SolidJS + SUID?

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js, suid

I'm kind of new to SolidJS, and now I'm trying to work out how [SUID](https://suid.io/)'s `ThemeProvider` differs from SolidJS's (e.g. [this docs provider/context example](https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/stores_context?solved=)). A simple example would be how to switch between light and dark modes from a child component. What's the proper way?

I've tried something like this so far, but it hasn't worked, I thought signal reactivity would be enough, but I think I'm misunderstanding a core concept somewhere.

If the example below is successful, then the background should switch between black and white.

```
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

import { createTheme } from "@suid/material";
import { green, orange } from "@suid/material/colors";

const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "light",
    background: {
      default: "#000",
    },
  }
});

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",
    background: {
      default: "#fff",
    },
  }
});

const [theme, setTheme] = createSignal(darkTheme);

function toggleTheme() {
  theme() === lightTheme
    ? setTheme(darkTheme)
    : setTheme(lightTheme);
}

function ChildComponent() {
  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      onChange={(e) => {
        toggleTheme();
      }}
      label=""
      control={<Switch />}
    />
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme()}>
        <ChildComponent />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TLDR;

The way SolidJS works is pretty different from React. It tracks updates or reactivity based on function calls essentially, and we've to make use of [reactive primitives](https://www.solidjs.com/guides/reactivity#introducing-primitives) in SolidJS to be able to make sure that the UI is reactive. So, you'll need to create your theme by using a reactive primitive.

#### Setting the Baseline

The SolidJS's [guide to reactivity](https://www.solidjs.com/guides/reactivity#reactivity) outlines all the types of reactive primitives and how they work.

Reactivity in SolidJS only works if any reactive primitive is accessed in the a reactive scope, so to say, which is, any other reactive primitive (using a signal inside of a effect for instance) or inside of the JSX code. If this is the case, re-render occurs, and updates are reflected. To quote [SolidJS docs](https://www.solidjs.com/guides/reactivity#considerations) -

> 1. All reactivity is tracked from function calls whether directly or hidden beneath getter/proxy and triggered by property access. This means where you access properties on reactive objects is important.
> 2. Components and callbacks from control flows are not tracking scopes and only execute once. This means destructuring or doing logic top-level in your components will not re-execute. You must access these Signals, Stores, and props from within other reactive primitives or the JSX for that part of the code to re-evaluate.

The Signals & Memos return an `Accessor<T>` type which, when called, in a reactive scope causes an update. You'd think -

> ***But I'm using the signal inside of the JSX (in my example), and that's a reactive context, so what's wrong?***

Yes, you're using it like so, and it's not your fault that it doesn't work, it's `SUID`'s fault. Remember the rule about destructuring from the docs -

> This means destructuring or doing logic top-level in your components will not re-execute.

This is the reason it doesn't work. You see, the `SUID` library is just MUI using SolidJS instead of React. The architecture is same as MUI. To inject styles into all components, the MUI library makes use of [`styled`](https://mui.com/system/styled/) utility, if no `ThemeProvider` is used by user, a default theme is injected, otherwise, if a `ThemeProvider` is there, `useTheme` is used to get that theme and create components. Same is the case with `SUID`, it also [makes use of](https://github.com/swordev/suid/blob/main/packages/material/src/styles/styled.tsx) `useTheme` under the hood, for creating the components, which is nothing but destructuring like so -

```ts
const theme = useTheme();
```

So,the theme is getting updated, but there are no updates. Let's move on to debugging step by step.

#### Debugging: Understand What's Happening

In your example, you're trying to do it way it's done in React. I don't blame you. Let's use your example to compare with React to see what's really happening.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-theme-poc-fmcfcr) an example of React MUI, and [here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-templates-exeljc?file=src%2FApp.tsx) an example of SolidJS with SUID. When we click on the button in front of "***From Signal***" the handler fires in both the examples. However, the behavior isn't same. What's missing?

[image: Solid debug]
[image: MUI debug]

We see that in MUI, the theme state reflects properly on buttons and the theme mode reflects properly as well, however, in SolidJS the value of theme mode reflects properly from the button using the signal value but the button using theme from `useTheme` inside of the context, doesn't seem to be able to get it right. But it actually is getting the correct theme, SolidJS passes the objects as is through the `useContext` hook. This is happening because of destructuring, the UI doesn't re-render. Let me prove that to you.

Let's change some piece of code in our SolidJS example, to make it look like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-templates-lgmwta?file=src%2FApp.tsx), we'll pass the `theme` signal wrapped inside of an array instead of passing it plainly in the provider -- with that we'll need to make use of vanilla html components, because with an array type of theme, the lib components will error from not being able to access the theme.

[image: debug2]

> ***What? Both the buttons now reflect correct theme mode in SolidJS as well?***

Yes, because this time, we're destructuring an array, and it has the reference to the signal, so we just create a wrapper to get that value, and it works!

> ***Enough of all this now, how do I fix the theming then?***

Let's move on to that.

#### How to implement theming?

As mentioned at the start, we'll need to make use of reactive primitives, and as already seen, signals don't really help, so, we'll make use of the `createMemo` reactive primitive and [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-templates-d2xkso?file=src%2FApp.tsx) is the approach we'll take -

```ts
import {
  createTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
} from '@suid/material';
import Button from '@suid/material/Button';
import { createPalette } from '@suid/material/styles/createPalette';
import { createSignal, createMemo, createEffect } from 'solid-js';

function Btn(props: any) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        gap: '1rem',
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: '10px',
      }}
    >
      <Typography>From Context: </Typography>
      <Button variant="contained" color="success">
        {theme.palette.mode}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Counter(props: any) {
  const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = createSignal<'light' | 'dark'>('light');

  const palette = createMemo(() => {
    return createPalette({ mode: themeMode() });
  });

  const theme = createTheme({ palette: palette });

  function onClick() {
    setThemeMode((prev) => (prev === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          gap: '1rem',
          alignItems: 'center',
          margin: '10px',
        }}
      >
        <Typography>From Signal: </Typography>
        <Button variant="contained" color="success" onClick={onClick}>
          {themeMode()}
        </Button>
      </div>
      <Btn />
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          gap: '1rem',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          margin: '15px 50px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        }}
      >
        SolidJS
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Now it works! We finally have our theming!

> ***Wait, why do we have to do it like this?***

The `createMemo` reactive primitive is a signal and an effect at the same time. It outputs a reactive value, and in all the functions where that reactive value is used, the function is registered on the SolidJS's runtime internal stack as a subscriber.

> ***So, can't I just use the `createTheme` inside of the `createMemo`?***

No, you can't. Reason being, if you use the `createMemo` like that, you'll get a `theme` object that's memoized and since the `useContext` hook passes the data as is, the theme object will be destructured like before by `useTheme` and we'll lose reactivity.

The reason why this approach works is, when the `themeMode` signal changes, the `palette` is created again, and with that, the `theme` variable is updated. After all that's done and the nodes in the tree are there, an effect is run to update the tree, and hence we see the theming work.

Comment: I think if read one the quoted sentence before that, it does make sense. But I also think it's better to be explicit, updating it.

Comment: @0xts Thank you for the amazingly thorough and patient answer, a well deserved bounty. Many things you've mentioned seem so subtle to catch for a new SolidJS user, really hard to catch.

Comment: @0xts Since you seem to be an expert at SolidJS, you might want to check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76924982/4756173) I've just put a bounty on, it's about D3.js with SolidJS and TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Solid does not have a theme provider but provides context API to create a theme provider in this case `ThemeProvider`.

`ThemeProvider` is component that passes a theme data down to its children. It is not only its direct children but an children that lives under it.

For the example, data is the value return by `theme()` signal.

`FormControlLabel`under `ChildComponent` provides a way to toggle dark and light themes by swapping the active theme through `setTheme`.

Any component that has access to `setTheme`can set a new theme.

A new theme can be created via `createTheme`. It provides minimum requirements for a theme value. A theme is an object with a value called `palette` that has `mode` etc.

What you are trying to do is to use a context value to pass data, a JavaScript object with CSS values, to downstream components. Since code has no issue but you don't know how it works, it is best for you to learn how solid works and how context API fits into its reactive system.

You can check out this answer for how to use Context API:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74492899/7134134

Comment: (I have trimmed out some meta-commentary from the answer here, as that won't be useful to future readers. This is not my subject area, but it looks like helpful material to me, even if it is not what the OP was seeking. All parties in this thread may wish to delete some of their comments given that agreement won't now be reached. Thanks folks.)